# How do I get for loop to check 1st line

Tags: javascript

I have a time register of vehicles that need to be loaded. I have a status that changes if the allowed waiting time is exceeded.

I use a for loop to check through lines, my loop starts from line 4 in my google sheet. My problem is that the loop only starts once I add the 5th line to the register. I know it is because the var i value is not smaller than 4, see below. I do know how to get it to check line 4 as well.   I am new to scripting so I would appreciate it if some can assist.

I run this function with a time trigger.

`for(var i=4;`**`i<=lastRow;`**`i++)`

Below is my code

```
function tankerWaiting() {

  var s = SpreadsheetApp;
  var sheet = s.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  Logger.log(lastRow);

 //i is 1st line of the regiter
  for(var i=4;i<=lastRow;i++){
    var currentWaitingTime = sheet.getRange(i, 5);
    var waitingLimit = sheet.getRange(2, 5);

    if(currentWaitingTime.getValue() > waitingLimit.getValue()){
      sheet.getRange(i, 6).setValue("Tanker still waiting!");
}
```

Comment: i=4 is line 5 - JS iterators  start at 0

Comment: `for(var i=3; i<=lastRow; i++)`?

Comment: @mplungjan thank you for your reply however if I change the 4 value to 0 the script does not execute.

Comment: If you want to start at line 4, change to 3

Comment: @BenM thanks, I tried that and if I look at trigger executions I can see the script run however my status cell is not being updated.

Comment: @mplungjan my register headings are in line 3 and script runs but no change to status.

Comment: Because the index of your line 3 is 2. Index start from 0. So i=0=>1st line. i=1=>2nd line etc

Comment: Thank you for trying guys as a workaround I will have to make line 4 an example on how to complete register.